# Dirrect way to get content of current open page into main.js file in FireFox add-on sdk

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I have one problem with add-on Firefox sdk. I'm searching a way to get content of current working page into main.js file. The application is based on widget that open popup when is clicked. I have one idea. To inject content script into open with sdk/page-worker and this content script using port API (self.port.emit) to trigger event and pass document.body.innerHTML. Like this:

```
self.port.emit("getCurrentPageHtml", document.body.innerHTML);
```

And into main.js file:

```
popupName.port.on("getCurrentPageHtml", function (receivedHtml) {
   // handle received html
});
```

But will be very good idea if there is some direct API and avoid this communication.

I would appreciate any advice and tips.

Best regards.

Comment: main.js is really bad at interacting with the DOM. Why do you want to import the whole page? Are you trying to put the current page into the widget? Usually one does all DOM manipulations in the content script, then passes back any values you want to store or manipulate.

Comment: No. I dont trying to put the current page into the widget. Never mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question for the second time today. Pity. Apparently there is no direct way to do this. So we can listen for panel event with popuVar.port.on. After this we can use:

```
// must be required tab api
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs
tabs.activeTab.url
```

and use page-worker on this url https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker. After this content script of this page worker will trigger event to get html of page. Another option is just made request to url of current page.

Comment: But **why do you need to get the whole page into main.js?** I really don't think this is the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: In fact, this is the task. Text in the page will be send to service for analysis. Then this service will return annotations.